# Connected components of Facebook

Tags: api, social-media, network-structure

On the basis of publicly available data, is it possible to reasonably estimate:

1. The size of facebook.com's largest graph-theoretic connected component, where two users are connected if and only if they are friends?
2. The number of connected components?

Comment: have a hard time believing anything about facebook is open, let alone data.